# Magento 2: Update product attribute from text area to wysiwyg programmatically

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-edit

I want to update the custom product attribute from textarea to WYSIWYG programmatically.
InstallData.php file:

```
      $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'Tekglide_video_description',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Video Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => "",
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'group' => 'Video',
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
```

product_form.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="video">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <container name="container_Tekglide_video_enabled">
            <field name="Tekglide_video_enabled">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">Tekglide_video_enabled</item>
                        <item name="switcherConfig" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                            <item name="rules" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_title.Tekglide_video_title</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_embedcode.Tekglide_video_embedcode</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_link.Tekglide_video_link</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="3" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_label.Tekglide_video_label</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="4" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_description.Tekglide_video_description</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">hide</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                                    <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_title.Tekglide_video_title</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_embedcode.Tekglide_video_embedcode</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="2" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_link.Tekglide_video_link</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="3" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_label.Tekglide_video_label</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="4" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="target" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form.video.container_Tekglide_video_description.Tekglide_video_description</item>
                                            <item name="callback" xsi:type="string">show</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Tekglide_VideoTab/js/form/element/options</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </container>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was simple. Just needed to create a UpgradeData.php file in my module:

```
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if ($context->getVersion() && version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(4, 'Tekglide_video_description', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
            $eavSetup->updateAttribute(4, 'Tekglide_video_description', 'is_wysiwyg_enabled', 1);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```